# How to set / switch language for my Xpages application

Tags: cookies, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I want to support my application in multiple languages.

I want the application to remember the user choice via a cookie so the user does not need to set the language with every visit.

I experience problems with setting the languages and changing the language. Somewhere the changes are not set properly.

Here is how I have come so far. I got two buttons to select language:

```
<xp:button value="English">
    <xp:this.disabled><![CDATA[#{javascript:return context.getLocaleString().equals("en")}]]></xp:this.disabled>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:setLanguage('en')
context.reloadPage()}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
|
<xp:button value="Svenska">
    <xp:this.disabled><![CDATA[#{javascript:return context.getLocaleString().equals("sv")}]]></xp:this.disabled>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:setLanguage('sv')
context.reloadPage()}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

In setLanguage I both create a cookie and set the language for the context:

```
function setLanguage(lang){
    //create/overwrite cookie first
    var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse(); 
    var userCookie = new javax.servlet.http.Cookie("userLanguage",  lang);
    userCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*10); // set age in seconds...
    userCookie.setPath("/"); // cookie will be valid under this path
    response.addCookie(userCookie);     
    //set language for context
    context.setLocaleString(lang);
}
```

I have a function for reading the cookie:

```
function getCookie(cookieName){
    var c = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestCookieMap().get(cookieName)
    return (c!=null)?c.getValue():""
}
```

The code I found here originally:
https://oliverbusse.notesx.net/Privat/osnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?documentId=00697A5B1012D029C1257B320005775D

For every page I compare the value in the cookie with the context and if there is a difference (e.g. user switches selection or has a different locale in the context I set the language too and initialize default values that I use for keywords in multiple languages:

```
function initLanguage(){
    var reset = false;
    var userLanguage = getCookie("userLanguage")
    var localLanguage = context.getLocaleString();
    if(userLanguage != ""){
        if (userLanguage != localLanguage){
            setLanguage(userLanguage);
            reset = true;
        }
    } else{
        if (localLanguage.equals("sv_SV")){
            setLanguage('sv');
            reset = true;
        }else if (localLanguage.equals("en_EN")){
            setLanguage('en');
            reset = true;
        }else if (localLanguage.equals("en_US")){
            setLanguage('en');
            reset = true;
        }       
    }   
    if (reset){
        init();
        context.reloadPage();       
    }
}
```

Somehow I managed to write a conflict or in the context reload the changes disappear :-?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the answer is that you are setting **sv** and **en** in the cookie but testing against context locallang that is probably not sv because you are testing for **sv_SV**